# Composed Task is giving Error in Spring cloud data flow server

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

When i create tasks independently they are working fine, but when i add the same tasks to composed task it is giving below error

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataFlowOperations' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/task/app/composedtaskrunner/DataFlowConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowOperations]: Factory method 'dataFlowOperations' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute`

I followed the steps mentioned here : https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/2.3.x/feature-guides/batch/composed-task/#registering-composed-task-runner

This error i am getting only from SCDF server, hosted in pcf.
I am able to execute the composed task in my local scdf server.

This is the DSL i am trying
`timelabel1: timestamp && timelabel2: timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this by passing below argument while launching task

`--arguments "--dataflow-server-uri=https:<data-flow-serrver-url>"`